# Hide FAB without removing or hiding Bottom appbar in android

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button, bottomnavigationview

I have a Base Activity with bottom appbar and 3 fragments A, B, C in it. I want to hide FAB in fragment A but maintaining the bottom appbar. I tried many ways but none of them worked.

1. calling myfab.hide() in fragment A (in onCreate or onViewCreated). Not helpful
2. Using `navControler` in MainActivity  as follow: (Not helpful)

```
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener((controller, destination, args) -> {
        if(destination.getId()== R.id.fragment_A){
           myfab.hide();
       }
    });
```

3. setting `myfab` visibility to gone or invisible (Not helpful)

Is there any way I can hide fab without removing or hiding bottom appbar?

here is my main Layout that contain bottom appbar and FAB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/appToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/green"
        app:collapseIcon="@drawable/ic_gear"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow"
        app:navigationIconTint="@color/white"
        app:titleCentered="true"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/TitleFont" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/mainBottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/green"
        app:collapseIcon="@drawable/ic_cancel"
        app:elevation="@dimen/card_view_elevation"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        app:fabAnimationMode="slide"
        app:fabCradleMargin="@dimen/corner_radius"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="@dimen/card_view_corner_radius"
        app:hideOnScroll="false"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu"
        app:navigationIconTint="@color/white" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/main_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_gears"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/green"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="@dimen/card_view_elevation"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/mainBottomAppBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```